# Python, Circular Shortest Path

Tags: python, algorithm, geometry, shortest-path

I am trying to make strange shortest path finder method. But I don't know how I can.

I need a algorithm. I did some research and found some algorithm for finding shortest path, like Dijkstra's algorithm, Floyd–Warshall algorithm, Johnson's algorithm. But I think they don't meet my expectation.

[image]

I want that: Should start at red dots, should walk through all blue dots and ends at red dot.

Is there a algorithm for that?

*(Really sorry for my English. I hope you can understand me.)*

Comment: This is a simple variation of the [traveling salesman problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem), which unfortunately means that it could be extremely difficult, depending on the size of your graph and how good the path needs to be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is a variant of a [Hamiltonian Cycle Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem), which is [NP-Complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete), so there is no known efficient solution to it (and most believe a solution does not exist, but it is not proven yet)

The Hamiltonian Cycle Problem says: Given a graph `G=(V,E)`, find if there is a simple cycle (each vertex is traversed at most once) that goes through all vertices, and is a classic NP-Complete Problem.

The reduction is quite simple, given a Hamiltonian Cycle Problem, color one random point in red, and the rest of the points in blue. There is a solution to the Hamiltonian Cycle Problem if and only if the solution to your problem is a simple path on the "modified" problem on the new graph.

---

Since the problem is NP-Complete, it means there is no known optimal efficient solution for it. You can try using some brute force techniques that might be feasible for small graphs, or sattle for approximation/heuristic solutions.

Comment: It seems more Traveling Salesman than Hamiltonian Cycle to me, considering that it doesn't seem like it'd be a problem to go through a dot twice.

Comment: @user2357112 Read the reduction made. The Hamiltonian Cycle and TSP are varients of each other as well, actually.